# Canvas- Eraser drawing black lines over canvas after canvas saved as image

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, angular6

Drawing on canvas is working perfectly fine. Even eraser also working perfectly fine. Issue is that while canvas saved as image it's drawing black lines instead of eraser.

For better understanding I added screens shots and code.

**1. While erasing the draw -**

**a. Source code -**

```
erase(){
      this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    } 

handleMove(ev){

  // let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
  let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetX;
  let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetY;

  this.ctx.beginPath();
  this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
  this.ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
  this.ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
  this.ctx.closePath();
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.currentColour;
  this.ctx.lineWidth = this.brushSize;
  this.ctx.stroke();      


  this.undoList.push({
    x_start: currentX,
    y_start: currentY,
    x_end: this.lastX,
    y_end: this.lastY,
    color: this.currentColour,
    size: this.brushSize,
    mode: this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation
  });

  this.lastX = currentX;
  this.lastY = currentY;
  
}
```

**b. Output -**

[image]

**2. Canvas saved as an Image -**

**a. Code -**

```
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);
    setTimeout(() => {
      
      // this.drawImg(this.newImg);
       for(let i=0; i<this.textAreasList.length; i++){
         let txt = this.textAreasList[i];
         this.ctx.font = this.textAreasList[i].bold + ' ' + this.textAreasList[i].italic + ' ' + this.textAreasList[i].fontSize + ' ' + 'Comic Sans MS';
         this.ctx.fillStyle = this.textAreasList[i].color;  
         if(this.textAreasList[i].left=="" || this.textAreasList[i].left==undefined) {
           this.textAreasList[i].left = 50;
         }
         if(this.textAreasList[i].top=="" || this.textAreasList[i].top==undefined) {
          this.textAreasList[i].top = 50;
        }
         this.ctx.fillText(this.textAreasList[i].value, this.textAreasList[i].left, this.textAreasList[i].top);
       }

       this.redrawCanvas(this.undoUseList);
       let imgPath = this.canvasElement.toDataURL('image/png');
       let message= "";
       this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(imgPath).then(
         res => message = "Image saved to gallery!",
         err => message = "Something went wrong!!"
       );
       this.spinner.hide();
       let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
         message: message,
         duration: 3000,
         position: 'bottom',
         cssClass: 'changeToast'
       });
       this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
     }, 5000);
  }



redrawCanvas(arr){
      // this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j< arr[i].length; j++){
          let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = arr[i][j].mode;
          console.log('x start', arr[i][j].x_start);
          console.log('y start', arr[i][j].y_start);
          console.log('x end', arr[i][j].x_end);
          console.log('y end', arr[i][j].y_end);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineJoin = "round";
          ctx.moveTo(arr[i][j].x_start, arr[i][j].y_start);
          ctx.lineTo(arr[i][j].x_end, arr[i][j].y_end);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.strokeStyle = arr[i][j].color;
          ctx.lineWidth = arr[i][j].size;
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        
      }
      
    }

**b. Output -**
```

[image]

I am not understanding how come eraser moves getting replaced with black colour while saving canvas as an image.

Comment: What is the image format you are using?

Comment: I am using png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue. I did below changes.

```
redrawCanvas(arr){
      // this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j< arr[i].length; j++){
          let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
          // ctx.globalCompositeOperation = arr[i][j].mode;

          if(arr[i][j].mode== "destination-out"){
            // ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destionation-out";
            // ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
            let cImg = new Image();
            cImg.src = this.selectedImage;
            let pattern = ctx.createPattern(cImg, "no-repeat");
            ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
          }else{
            ctx.strokeStyle = arr[i][j].color;
          }
          console.log('x start', arr[i][j].x_start);
          console.log('y start', arr[i][j].y_start);
          console.log('x end', arr[i][j].x_end);
          console.log('y end', arr[i][j].y_end);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineJoin = "round";
          ctx.moveTo(arr[i][j].x_start, arr[i][j].y_start);
          ctx.lineTo(arr[i][j].x_end, arr[i][j].y_end);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.lineWidth = arr[i][j].size;
          ctx.stroke();
        }

      }

    }
```

As you can see, I have added one check to check whether it's brush or eraser. For eraser I am checking whether it's `destination-out` or not.

If it is eraser, I am creating new image, to make `strokestyle`.

So you can say I did below change only.

```
if(arr[i][j].mode== "destination-out"){
            // ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destionation-out";
            // ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
            let cImg = new Image();
            cImg.src = this.selectedImage;
            let pattern = ctx.createPattern(cImg, "no-repeat");
            ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
          }else{
            ctx.strokeStyle = arr[i][j].color;
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

So, you're redrawing your canvas using the undo list, right? And after that you output the image using toDataUrl()?

It seems to me that the issue lies on

```
this.undoList.push({
  x_start: currentX,
  y_start: currentY,
  x_end: this.lastX,
  y_end: this.lastY,
  color: this.currentColour, <== Is this an object?
  size: this.brushSize,
  mode: this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation
});
```

if this.currentColour is an object, I guess that the properties are changed somewhere else in the code and by the time you reconstruct the steps, you get the style black, not sure if it is the default one.

so you can try this instead

```
this.undoList.push({
  x_start: currentX,
  y_start: currentY,
  x_end: this.lastX,
  y_end: this.lastY,
  color: {
    prop1: this.currentColour.prop1
    prop2: this.currentColour.prop2
    ...
  }
  size: this.brushSize,
  mode: this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation
});
```

replacing prop1, prop2, etc by the actual properties you have in that object. In this way you are creating a new obj (copying it) instead of passing a ref to your old one.

You can make it fancier, but like this you can get the reasoning better.